# discord.py - How to warn system in python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to use a warning system for a long time, but I always have an error. Can someone give me an example or something for a warning system? Would be very nice!
By the way, I try [`@bot.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) in `python3.8`. The bot should then be able to:

```
-Warn command
-Banned words
-save the warnings
-read the warnings
```

Comment: What is a warning? Do you have a design doc?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written?